# Swift didSet on UICollectionViewCell property running, but not updating UI

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionviewcell, property-observer

I have a custom `UICollectionViewCell` that changes its appearance in response to selection events, and *should* change its appearance in response to other property changes, too, but doesn't.

```
class NumberCell: UICollectionViewCell {
    let numberLabel = UILabel()

    override var selected: Bool {
        didSet {
            // Updates as expected
            contentView.backgroundColor = self.selected ? UIColor.redColor() : UIColor.clearColor()
        }
    }

    var number: Int? {
        didSet {
            // Sets and shows the text in the number label as expected when cell is first initialised
            if let number = number {
                numberLabel.text = String(number)
            }
        }
    }

    var isCrossedOut: Bool = false {
        didSet {
            // Sets and displays correct values on initialisation, but later
            // stops updating display
            contentView.backgroundColor = self.isCrossedOut ? UIColor.blackColor() : UIColor.clearColor()
        }
    }

    // ...
}
```

The selected state for the cell updates nicely, but whenever I do `cell.isCrossedOut = true`, I can see the code running, but I don't see the background colour actually changing, even though it seems to be using exactly the same logic as the selection property observer.

I can trigger a visual update by doing `collectionView.reloadData()` (not acceptable to reload the entire collection view), or `collectionView.reloadItemsAtIndexPaths([...])` (more or less acceptable I guess), but I really would prefer to update the UI dynamically.

**EDIT**

This is how I update the crossed out property:

```
func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    if shouldBeCrossedOut(indexPath) {
        let cell = self.collectionView(collectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath: indexPath) as! NumberCell
        cell.isCrossedOut = true
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you sure that after calling `isCrossedOut` `selected` is not called?

Comment: @Andrea thanks, but yes, I'm sure. It is not only the background colour that fails to update, I could change any other property of the cell's UI and that wouldn't work either.

Comment: Can you show the code for when you set cell.isCrossedOut? Your code works for me: `let cell = self.collectionView?.cellForItemAtIndexPath(NSIndexPath(forItem: 0, inSection: 0)) as! NumberCell;
        cell.isCrossedOut = !cell.isCrossedOut;`

Comment: I believe `.reloadItemsAtIndexPaths` is the way to go, and that it's expected that the view on the cell doesn't update unless reloading is called. It's actually curious that mutating `selection` also shows a GUI update/reload. From [language ref. for `UICollectionViewCell`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UICollectionViewCell_class/): _"You typically do not set the value of this property directly._ _Changing the value of this property programmatically does not change the appearance of the cell_."

Comment: If you print isCrossedOut in `didSet` is the value you are expecting ? also change your code in `didSet(oldValue)` so that you can see the previous value

Comment: @Andrea yes, it is getting the expected value, running at the correct time, just not displaying the UI updates.

Comment: @dfri thanks. it's hard for me to believe though that collection view cells are incapable of dynamic UI updates – what if you want to trigger cell appearance changes in response to user actions that don't have anything to do with the data model, in which case reloading the cell would not work? Surely this is possible?

Comment: @Elise I agree that it should be possible (and possibly is via some clever hack, however nothing that I could help out with, perhaps someone else can), but I have generally got the feeling from the `UIKit` members that they prefer to use their innate methods and properties to actually redraw/update the UI part of themselves.

Comment: @Elise the simple way to test it, is create a small project with the same logic a some sample data, beyowulf says it works and I bet I did something similar in the past without a problem, but I can't find the project. If you want to perform a full redraw set after setting the background color         `setNeedsDisplay() displayIfNeeded()`(Can affect scrolling performance)

Comment: @dfri got it.. thanks for your comments.

Comment: @Andrea thanks, will do.. I've already tried `setNeedsDisplay()` and `displayIfNeeded()` – no change :(

Comment: @Elise Happy to (attempt to) help, but note that this is just my own experience with updating UIKit members, perhaps someone else can help you out with a workaround.

Comment: @Elise very weird that you don't believe that your code works as is. Like I requested perhaps you can show us the code for when you set isCrossedOut. I have set in the IBAction of a bar button item and as set with the code above and it turns black. I have not altered your NumberCell class at all. If I had to guess, I would say you are calling dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier rather than cellForItemAtIndexPath

Comment: https://github.com/bgayman/CollectionView

Comment: @beyowulf much appreciated, however I don't use any storyboards in my project so I suspect some differences might be creeping in in that regard to how the cell is updated. Also, the code for how I update `isCrossedOut` is in an Edit in my question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace:

```
self.collectionView(collectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath: indexPath) as! NumberCell
```

With:

```
self.collectionView?.cellForItemAtIndexPath(NSIndexPath(forItem: 0, inSection: 0)) as! NumberCell
```

`self.collectionView(collectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath: indexPath) as! NumberCell` is the datasource method you override to supply the collection view with a cell (i.e. it will always return a newly instantiated or a newly dequeued cell, and thus one that is not currently on screen). `self.collectionView?.cellForItemAtIndexPath(NSIndexPath(forItem: 0, inSection: 0)) as! NumberCell` is an instance method that will return a reference to the current cell at a given index path. Storyboards are not relevant to this problem. You can view a code for a playground with effective code with no IB whatsoever [here](https://gist.github.com/bgayman/6dbd364e46030ebd2714).

Comment: That did it! I knew it must have been something ridiculously simple like that... Thanks!